# How can I modify this DT theme to make it look more like another

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

Hello I am using in R this port of the [datatable javascript library](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/)

When I render a table the "look" is like the following: [notice the round edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gN4o.png)

I noticed a python dash app using the same library looking like the following
[notice the square edges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkDnA.png)

In R my code looks like this, the issue might be the "theme", how can I modify the "round one", so it looks more like the "square one"

```
   table = datatable(data,   
                      width='100%', 
                      selection=list(mode='multiple', target='column'), 
                      style='bootstrap', 
                      filter = list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE, plain = FALSE), 
                      extensions = c('Buttons', 'ColReorder'), 
                      options = list(pageLength=30, autoWidth=TRUE, columnDefs=list(list(classname='dt-center')), dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel'), colReorder=TRUE)) %>% 
    formatStyle( 0, target= 'row',color = 'black', fontWeight ='bold', lineHeight='50%')
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. The boxes are not "round" by default and even with your code I get square boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, I don' understand what you mean, because for me the boxes are square.

Anyway, if you want to control the roundess of the boxes, you can do:

```
datatable(head(iris),   
          filter = list(position = 'top', clear = TRUE, plain = FALSE),
          options = list(
            initComplete = JS("function(settings){
              $('input[type=\"search\"]').each(function(){
                $(this).css('border-radius','100px'); // set to 0 for square boxes
              })
            }")
          )
) %>% 
  formatStyle( 0, target= 'row',color = 'black', fontWeight ='bold', lineHeight='50%')
```